# What is the best way to clean a dryer vent?

Tags: cleaning, vent, dryer, ducts

I posted this questions 6 months ago..

[Why does it take my dryer 3 hours to dry a load of clothes?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/26415/why-does-it-take-my-dryer-3-hours-to-dry-a-load-of-clothes)

I checked the cycling thermostat and thermal fuse. They are operational. I have seen different ways professionals clean dryer vent ductwork. Coit services used a portable compressor to blow air into the vent the push out lint. There was a good amount that came out.
But I have seen another method where they used a rod with rotating brush that push out lint. I am thinking of hiring someone to do it this way. Is this a better way than what Coit did?

My tenant last said the timning of drying has improved form 3 hours down to 2 hours. I'm not sure how long of dryer vent ductwork she had at her previous residence. I can understand if she had a dryer close to an exterior wall with a 1 foot of dryer vent. I may have to ask her that. Everything is relative. If there is a longer run of duct it should take longer to dry no? Any feedback would be appreciated. We really want to take care of this tenant because they are nice people.

Comment: If you have a shop vac, I'd just blow it out with that. High volume over high pressure because of the size of the tube and type of blockage. A brush is a more mechanical type of cleaning and has a better potential to remove smaller build ups. Think of the cholesterol medicine ads showing an artery blockage, there is still plenty of room to allow things to pass but also a chance for things to get caught easier and cause a blockage.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What is the best way to clean your clothes dryer exhaust?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/5401/2196)

Comment: Length of run and number of bends is certainly a factor in drying time. So is fuel source. In my experience natural gas dryers dry a fair bit faster than electric, given similar residential style machines. This too could account for the tenant's varying experiences. 2 hours may be within the range of normal for a fully loaded electric dryer.

Comment: I'm not sure if the tenant will accept that answer from me. When a technician came out to check if the dryer was actually working, he suggested to dry clothes but disconnect the vent ductwork to see if indeed dryer is working and something is wrong with the ductwork. I'm going to try that out.. I hate to clean the ductwork again

Answer (score 1):

I use a dryer vent brush like this one at Wal Mart:[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just did this this weekend. I imagine the answer really depends on the particulars of your duct work. Does it have a lot of bends? What's it made of? How long is it? Etc.

In our case, we had smooth vent pipe, but they used 2' pieces to span about 14'. So we had all these tiny pieces with joints which, on top of that, they 'sealed' with duct tape. Needless to say, all of these poorly connected joints were creating spots where lint was collecting and eventually clogging.

I took it all apart and began using the lint brush as shown in another answer, and it worked OK, but much of the lint was caked on to the point I had to scrape it off with a hard tool (screwdriver).

In the end, I went out and purchased a brand new 10' section instead, and then put it all back together with proper metallic tape. Dryer works much better now. I figure with an annual check I should be able to keep it fairly clean.

Answer (score 0):

While cleaning out the duct work is a great idea, lint clogging the vent shouldn't be a frequent problem.  Once every year or two ought to be overkill.

I would inspect the dryer's lint filter for holes and the lint frame for defects.  Definitely educate the tenant on the importance of the lint filter's proper use, including cleaning before *every* load.  If they are resistant or hard to educate, pay for a professional say once per year.  If the vent needs cleaning more often than that, charge it to the tenants:  they have control over how much lint is going into the vent.

Also, you might want to observe usage of the dryer.  If it is filled full, then poor performance is to be expected—I would not be surprised by three hours in that case.  There needs to be room for air to flow through the dryer during operation.  If a "full" load were split into two loads, I bet both "half" loads can be completed in 1.5 hours total, if not faster.

Comment: the tenants would tell me before that with even a handful of wet-shirts it would take a long time...now this sounds silly but usually people would use a spin cycle to wring excess water? i was thinking maybe they could possibly putting in really wet clothes