# How can I find where the dryer vent is broken or clogged?

Tags: dryer, venting

I live on the second floor of a three story condo building.We had a company come in to clean our dryer venting, and they said they could not pull a vacuum.The company said that that the venting is clogged or pulled apart.How do I find were it is clogged or pulled apart without tearing down my entire ceiling or wall?

Comment: I would think a pulled apart vent would result in a lot of vacuum, just not going back to the dryer. It should be very easy for them to tell the difference between a clog and a disconnected vent. And they make tools for cleaning dryer vents.

Comment: If your vent is clogged, the question you should be asking is how to clean it, not where is the clog. In which case "[What is the best way to clean your clothes dryer exhaust?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/5401/2196)" should be helpful.

Comment: A professional should have been able to tell the difference between clogged and pulled apart.  Also keep in mind if your vent needs cleaning, chances are all the other units need it also.  Perhaps the HOA can hire real professionals to do them all, justifying it as lowering fire risk.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to run an inspection camera through it in order to identify exactly where the break or clog is.  Though, as the comments suggest, often it's easier and cheaper to just run a cleaning tool through to unclog it versus first running an inspection camera through.

I would probably only resort to an inspection camera if it became a chronic problem, which would suggest an issue in the pipe (sharp bend, collapse, etc.).  If it has only clogged once, and you've never cleaned it before, its quite possible it just clogged from normal use over a long time.